# Facebook share change Domain Name

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

[image]

Hi everyone, I would like to customise the messaged displayed here. Currently it is displaying my domain or the ip of my server. I have tried using a few ways but the official facebook documentation has image, title, url and description but does not have this field.

Comment: You’re not supposed to be able to “customize” this (at least the domain/IP part, the “by …” part depends on the author profile you can specify via OG meta data), it is placed there so that users can see where content comes from … fake news etc., you know.

Comment: @04FS thanks a lot for your reply, I have tried a sample like this one here :

http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript

They are able to display my app name instead of the domain name, however the sharing results show :


    [username] shared an object on [app name] 

instead of 


     [username] has shared a link.

I'm fine with the output ( shared an object) , but is there anywhere in the docs that actually tells us how to do so ?

Comment: That is the automatic result of using `method: 'share_open_graph', action_type: 'og.likes'` in the FB.ui dialog call.